# a small traditional shop vs a traditional small shop

Tags: word-meaning

Are there differences between "a small traditional shop"
and "a traditional small shop".

In my opinion, a small traditional shop sells all hand made products inside. Very good local oil,spices,olives even hand made icons on old piece of wood.Also small hand made jewelry.

Traditional small shops range from family run grocery shops to stores selling flowers, tea and tobacco.

Answer (score 2):

"A small traditional shop means":

> A traditional shop which is small

And "a traditional small shop" means

> A shop that is in the traditional style of being small

The first adjective you are using is being used to describe the second adjective, so you get a "traditional small", and a "small traditional", meaning different things.